# Why I obtain this InstantiationException when I use the JdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper class in this Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I am working on a batch developed using Spring and I have some problem trying to obtain a list of objects from a query using Sping **JdbcTemplate** and **BeanPropertyRowMapper** Spring class that map a property of the class with a field of the database table.

So, on my database (Microsoft SQL Server) I have a table named **TassoRendimentoInterno** that contains the following column with the following data types:

```
ID  bigint
Conferimento    nvarchar
PolizzaID   bigint
ControvaloreQuote   decimal
percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione  money
percRendimentoInizioAnno    money
percRendimentoInizioTrimestre   money
AnnoRiferimento int
TipoRendimento  nchar
TipoTrasmissione    nchar
FlagQuoteOK bit
DataInizioposizione datetime
DataInizioAnno  datetime
DataInizioTrimestre datetime
DataFinePosizione   datetime
QuotePuc    decimal
DataRiferimentoNavPUC   datetime
TIMESTAMP   datetime
controvalorePUC money
dataRiferimentoNavTIR   datetime
DataRiferimentoFlusso   datetime
```

Then I have mappped this table with this class named **TassoRendimentoInterno**:

```
public class TassoRendimentoInterno {

    private String conferimento;
    private long polizzaID;
    private BigDecimal controvaloreQuote;
    private BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione;
    private BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioAnno;
    private BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioTrimestre;
    private int annoRiferimento;
    private String tipoRendimento;
    private String tipoTrasmissione;
    private boolean flagQuoteOK;
    private Timestamp dataInizioposizione;
    private Timestamp dataInizioAnno;
    private Timestamp dataInizioTrimestre;
    private Timestamp dataFinePosizione;
    private BigDecimal quotePuc;
    private Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavPUC;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private BigDecimal controvalorePUC;
    private Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavTIR;
    private Timestamp dataRiferimentoFlusso;


    public TassoRendimentoInterno(String conferimento, long polizzaID,
            BigDecimal controvaloreQuote,
            BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione,
            BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioAnno,
            BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioTrimestre, int annoRiferimento,
            String tipoRendimento, String tipoTrasmissione,
            boolean flagQuoteOK, Timestamp dataInizioposizione,
            Timestamp dataInizioAnno, Timestamp dataInizioTrimestre,
            Timestamp dataFinePosizione, BigDecimal quotePuc,
            Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavPUC, Timestamp timestamp,
            BigDecimal controvalorePUC, Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavTIR,
            Timestamp dataRiferimentoFlusso) {
        super();
        this.conferimento = conferimento;
        this.polizzaID = polizzaID;
        this.controvaloreQuote = controvaloreQuote;
        this.percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione = percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione;
        this.percRendimentoInizioAnno = percRendimentoInizioAnno;
        this.percRendimentoInizioTrimestre = percRendimentoInizioTrimestre;
        this.annoRiferimento = annoRiferimento;
        this.tipoRendimento = tipoRendimento;
        this.tipoTrasmissione = tipoTrasmissione;
        this.flagQuoteOK = flagQuoteOK;
        this.dataInizioposizione = dataInizioposizione;
        this.dataInizioAnno = dataInizioAnno;
        this.dataInizioTrimestre = dataInizioTrimestre;
        this.dataFinePosizione = dataFinePosizione;
        this.quotePuc = quotePuc;
        this.dataRiferimentoNavPUC = dataRiferimentoNavPUC;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.controvalorePUC = controvalorePUC;
        this.dataRiferimentoNavTIR = dataRiferimentoNavTIR;
        this.dataRiferimentoFlusso = dataRiferimentoFlusso;
    }
    public String getConferimento() {
        return conferimento;
    }
    public void setConferimento(String conferimento) {
        this.conferimento = conferimento;
    }
    public long getPolizzaID() {
        return polizzaID;
    }
    public void setPolizzaID(long polizzaID) {
        this.polizzaID = polizzaID;
    }
    public BigDecimal getControvaloreQuote() {
        return controvaloreQuote;
    }
    public void setControvaloreQuote(BigDecimal controvaloreQuote) {
        this.controvaloreQuote = controvaloreQuote;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPercRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione() {
        return percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione;
    }
    public void setPercRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione(
            BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione) {
        this.percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione = percRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPercRendimentoInizioAnno() {
        return percRendimentoInizioAnno;
    }
    public void setPercRendimentoInizioAnno(BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioAnno) {
        this.percRendimentoInizioAnno = percRendimentoInizioAnno;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPercRendimentoInizioTrimestre() {
        return percRendimentoInizioTrimestre;
    }
    public void setPercRendimentoInizioTrimestre(
            BigDecimal percRendimentoInizioTrimestre) {
        this.percRendimentoInizioTrimestre = percRendimentoInizioTrimestre;
    }
    public int getAnnoRiferimento() {
        return annoRiferimento;
    }
    public void setAnnoRiferimento(int annoRiferimento) {
        this.annoRiferimento = annoRiferimento;
    }
    public String getTipoRendimento() {
        return tipoRendimento;
    }
    public void setTipoRendimento(String tipoRendimento) {
        this.tipoRendimento = tipoRendimento;
    }
    public String getTipoTrasmissione() {
        return tipoTrasmissione;
    }
    public void setTipoTrasmissione(String tipoTrasmissione) {
        this.tipoTrasmissione = tipoTrasmissione;
    }
    public boolean isFlagQuoteOK() {
        return flagQuoteOK;
    }
    public void setFlagQuoteOK(boolean flagQuoteOK) {
        this.flagQuoteOK = flagQuoteOK;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataInizioposizione() {
        return dataInizioposizione;
    }
    public void setDataInizioposizione(Timestamp dataInizioposizione) {
        this.dataInizioposizione = dataInizioposizione;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataInizioAnno() {
        return dataInizioAnno;
    }
    public void setDataInizioAnno(Timestamp dataInizioAnno) {
        this.dataInizioAnno = dataInizioAnno;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataInizioTrimestre() {
        return dataInizioTrimestre;
    }
    public void setDataInizioTrimestre(Timestamp dataInizioTrimestre) {
        this.dataInizioTrimestre = dataInizioTrimestre;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataFinePosizione() {
        return dataFinePosizione;
    }
    public void setDataFinePosizione(Timestamp dataFinePosizione) {
        this.dataFinePosizione = dataFinePosizione;
    }
    public BigDecimal getQuotePuc() {
        return quotePuc;
    }
    public void setQuotePuc(BigDecimal quotePuc) {
        this.quotePuc = quotePuc;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataRiferimentoNavPUC() {
        return dataRiferimentoNavPUC;
    }
    public void setDataRiferimentoNavPUC(Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavPUC) {
        this.dataRiferimentoNavPUC = dataRiferimentoNavPUC;
    }
    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public BigDecimal getControvalorePUC() {
        return controvalorePUC;
    }
    public void setControvalorePUC(BigDecimal controvalorePUC) {
        this.controvalorePUC = controvalorePUC;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataRiferimentoNavTIR() {
        return dataRiferimentoNavTIR;
    }
    public void setDataRiferimentoNavTIR(Timestamp dataRiferimentoNavTIR) {
        this.dataRiferimentoNavTIR = dataRiferimentoNavTIR;
    }
    public Timestamp getDataRiferimentoFlusso() {
        return dataRiferimentoFlusso;
    }
    public void setDataRiferimentoFlusso(Timestamp dataRiferimentoFlusso) {
        this.dataRiferimentoFlusso = dataRiferimentoFlusso;
    }
}
```

Then I have this **MainApp** class (that simply obtain the DAO class named **PucManager pucManager**):

```
public class MainApp {

    private PucManager pucManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MainApp().execute(); 

    }

    private void execute() {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ConfigurableEnvironment conf = (ConfigurableEnvironment) context.getEnvironment();
        conf.setActiveProfiles("PROD"); 
        context.load("applicationContext.xml");
        context.refresh();

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        obj.getMessage();

        pucManager = (PucManager) context.getBean("pucManager");

        List<TassoRendimentoInterno> tassoRendimentoInternoList = pucManager.getTassoRendimentoInterno();

        List<TassoInternoRendimentoFondo> tassoInternoRendimentoFondoList = pucManager.getTassoRendimentoInternoFondo();

        System.out.println("BATCH TERMINATO");
    }
}
```

and this is my **PucManager** class:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class PucManager extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PucManager.class);
    private Connection con;

    public PucManager() {
        System.out.println("Costruzione PucManager");
    }

    @Autowired
    public PucManager(@Qualifier("dataSourcePUC") DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);

    }

    public String testMethod() {
        return "TEST OK";
    }


    public List<TassoRendimentoInterno> getTassoRendimentoInterno() {

        String sql = "select *  from puc001.TassoRendimentoInterno "
                   + "where Polizzaid in ( select id from polizza where prodottoid = '6v0u1' )";

        List<TassoRendimentoInterno> tassoRendimentoInternoList  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TassoRendimentoInterno.class));

        return tassoRendimentoInternoList;

    }

    public List<TassoInternoRendimentoFondo> getTassoRendimentoInternoFondo() {

        String sql = "select *  from puc001.TassoInternoRendimentoFondo "
                   + "where Polizzaid in ( select id from polizza where prodottoid = '6v0u1' )";

        List<TassoInternoRendimentoFondo> tassoInternoRendimentoFondoList  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TassoInternoRendimentoFondo.class));

        return tassoInternoRendimentoFondoList;

    }

}
```

The problem is that when it try to perform this instruction into the **getTassoRendimentoInterno()** method:

```
List<TassoRendimentoInterno> tassoRendimentoInternoList  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TassoRendimentoInterno.class));
```

I obtain this excption into the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.mycompany.beans.TassoRendimentoInterno]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mycompany.beans.TassoRendimentoInterno
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    at com.mycompany.dbmanager.PucManager.getTassoRendimentoInterno(PucManager.java:62)
    at com.mycompany.dbmanager.PucManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d6a10e62.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
    at com.mycompany.dbmanager.PucManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fbae53e4.getTassoRendimentoInterno(<generated>)
    at com.mycompany.main.MainApp.execute(MainApp.java:37)
    at com.mycompany.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mycompany.beans.TassoRendimentoInterno
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:79)
    ... 19 more
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [BeanPropertyRowMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html),

> RowMapper implementation that converts a row into a new instance of
>   the specified mapped target class. The mapped target class must be a
>   top-level class and it must have a default or no-arg constructor.

Looks like you miss a no-arg constructor in `TassoRendimentoInterno`